# Razor control not able to prepopulate data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have razor view with checkbox. I cant able to prepopulate checkbox with true/false . Here is my code

```
<label for="HousingBidsComps_99">&nbsp;</label>
<div class="check_box_group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="HousingBidsComps_99" name="HousingBidsComps[1].IsChargesIncluded" class="customCheckbox"  >
    <label for="HousingBidsComps_99" style="margin-bottom:0">
        <span style="margin-bottom:0">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HousingBidsComps[1].IsChargesIncluded, new { @class = "padd-left-0" })
        </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.HousingBidsComps[1].IsChargesIncluded)` - always use the `HtmlHelper` methods to bind to your model

Comment: And your two `<label>` elements make no sense - your `@Html.LabelFor()` is generating the correct `<label>`

Answer (score 2):

You should try to bind your checkbox like this:

```
<label for="HousingBidsComps_99">&nbsp;</label>
<div class="check_box_group">

  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.HousingBidsComps[1].IsChargesIncluded, new { @class="customCheckbox" })

    <label for="HousingBidsComps_99" style="margin-bottom:0">
        <span style="margin-bottom:0">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HousingBidsComps[1].IsChargesIncluded, new { @class = "padd-left-0" })
        </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: You DO NOT set the `checked` attribute in the `CheckBoxFor()` method! (its ignored fortunately since that would make the checkbox always checked  even if the property value was `false`)